# Power diagram (Laguerre tessellation)

Tags: computational-geometry

Is there a method to get a 2D [power diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram) from a set of points in the plane?

Comment: Based on the link @BobHanlon provided, it seems you need to have a set of circles, not points?

Comment: Yes, I'm dealing with points with weights, but geometrically, these can be interpreted as the radii of circles and the points as their centers

Comment: I have a function that takes in a point and tells you which circle it belongs to. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle circles that are entirely within other circles?

Comment: One algorithm to compute a power diagram is to project the intersection of 3D halfspaces to 2D. I tried RegionIntersection, but I don't know how to extract the edges or vertices that result from the intersection of halfspaces. If I could get these, I'd have a simple algorithm for computing the power diagram. Circles entirely contained in other circles are not a problem.

Comment: I have a method which uses `ConvexHullMesh[]`, but it's incomplete, since it can only give the interior cells. I haven't figured out how to make it generate the frontier cells as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[pDistance, lVor]
pDistance[{a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ}, {x_?NumericQ, 
    y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}] := Norm[{x, y} - {a, b}]^2 - (c - z)^2;

lVor[d : {{_, _, _} ..}][{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ}] :=
  First @ Nearest[d -> "Index", {x, y, z}, DistanceFunction -> pDistance]
```

***Examples:***

```
coords1 = {{0, 0, 2}, {1, 2/3, 2}};
coords2 = {{0, 0, 2}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}};
colors = ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2};

Row[RegionPlot[Evaluate[Table[lVor[#][{x, y, 0.}] == i, {i, 1, 2}]], 
    {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    Epilog -> {Thick, Thread[{colors, Circle[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ #}]}, 
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[
      Directive[FaceForm[Opacity[.3, #]], EdgeForm[{Thick, Opacity[1], #}]] & /@ colors, 
      Disk[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ #, LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
      LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]] & /@ 
  {coords1, coords2}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[77]
n = 5;
coords3 = Round[RandomReal[10, {n, 3}], .01];
colors3 = ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, n}}] /@ Range[n];

RegionPlot[Evaluate[Table[lVor[coords3][{x, y, 0.}] == i, {i, n}]],
  {x, -10, 20}, {y, -10, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> (Opacity[.3, #] & /@ colors3), 
 ImageSize -> Medium, 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Thread[{colors3, Circle[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ coords3}]}, 
 PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[
   Directive[FaceForm[Opacity[.3, #]], EdgeForm[{Thick, Opacity[1], #}]] & /@ colors3, 
   Disk[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ coords3, LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
   LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]]
```

[image]

With `n = 9` we get

[image]

Alternatively, we can use `lVor` with [`DensityPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityPlot.html):

```
colFunc = Blend[Transpose[{Range@n, colors3}], #] &;

DensityPlot[lVor[coords3][{x, y, 0}], {x, -10, 20}, {y, -10, 20}, 
 ColorFunction -> colFunc, BaseStyle -> FaceForm[Opacity[.4]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Epilog -> {Thick, Thread[{colors3, Circle[{#, #2}, #3] & @@@ coords3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Wizard. You are right; forgot to update the definition of `disks`. Fixed now.

Comment: Now it crashes Wolfram Kernel.  Maybe I'm just not destined to run this code. :^)

Comment: It looks nice in Wolfram Cloud. +1 I'm going to stop trying to make it work in 10.1.